# Making QGIS toolbox tool available directly from toolbar?

Tags: qgis, toolbar, toolbox

At QGIS 2.18.16, I commonly use a tool that is only available (AFAIK) through the Toolbox  (*Processing > Toolbox > QGIS Geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Frequency analysis*).

I would like to have this tool directly available on the toolbar, as a button or dropdown, so that it is more easily and quickly accessed.

A Google search turned up nothing.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could activate the '**Commander**' utility of Processing. From menù ***Processing*** -> ***Commander*** activate it.

After that you could choose the  Geoalgorithms from a dropdown menù (or type the beginnings letters) and then press *ENTER* on keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of Commander!  But I've rethought my original question - why are some QGIS tools "hidden away" in the toolbox, instead of always available in the normal menu?  I'm going to ask it as a new SE GIS question.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281505/why-are-some-qgis-tools-only-available-via-the-processing-toolbox/281516) you can install QGIS 3 and configure tools menu's and toolbars yourself.